# Ŝanĝiĝo de akcento rilate aldonon de -on al fremdaj nomoj

Tags: pronunciation, accusative

Mi legas la libron *La Fermita Urbo* de István Nemere. En tiu libro la aŭtoro uzas ne tute Esperantigitajn nomojn, ekzemple *Terlik*. Mi prononcus tion kiel *Térlik*, kun akcento sur la unua silabo (la antaŭlasta). La aŭtoro uzas aldonon de *-on* por montri akuzativon: *Terlik-on*. Kie estu la akcento? Ĉu mi diru *Terlík-on* aŭ *Térlik-on*?

Unuflanke, estas tri silaboj kaj, rigardante *Terlik-on* kiel unu vorton, oni tuj dirus *Terlík-on*, ĉar *i* estas la vokalo de la antaŭlasta silabo. Aliflanke, estas fremda nomo kaj *-on* estas disigita de la ‘radiko’; mi jam dirus *Térlik*, do havas sencon, ke la akcento estu tenata.

La aŭtoro kelkfoje uzas normalan akuzativan finaĵon, kiam la nomo finiĝas per vokalo: Lena → Lenan, Erni → Ernin. Klare, kvankam aldoni *n*-finaĵon al *Erni*, vorto finiĝanta per *i*, aspektas iom stranga, la akcenta silabo ne ŝanĝiĝas je aldono de akuzativo. Do eble ankaŭ en aliaj nomoj la akcento ne ŝanĝiĝu je aldono de akuzativo.

Verŝajne ne estas unuanima aŭ ununura ĝusta respondo al ĉi tiu demando. Tamen min interesas scii, kion farus vi kaj kial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vi pravas ke ne ekzistas ununura ĝusta kaj fina respondo. Malgraŭ tio, mi havas kelkajn konstatojn kiuj povos helpi vin.

- Ŝanĝo de akcento kiam oni aldonas sufikson estas normala afero en Esperanto:
  v**ó**rto, vort**á**ro, vortprov**í**zo, k**í**om, ki**ó**ma, pli (nur unusilaba), m**á**lpli.

  - Mi konscias ke ŝanĝo de akcento kiam oni aldonas -n ne okazas en normalaj esperantaj vortoj sed akcentoŝanĝo per si mem ne estas fremda al Esperanto.
- Bertilo ŝajne vidas streketon kiel signon kiu ne ŝanĝas la akcenton:

  - http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/apostrofo/nenormala_uzo.html#i-lhj
  - http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/ekkrioj_sonimitoj/elparolado_skribado.html
  - Rimarku ke li sugestas “ha lo” kaj “o kej” kaj **ne** “ha-lo” nek “o-kej”.

Tial Terl**í**k-on sonas sufiĉe bona por mi, kiel unu vorto (Terlíkon), okaze de nescio pri iu alia pli ĝusta prononco.

Mi mem havas pli grandan dubon pri kiel prononci Terlik: simple Terlik (é) aŭ kvazaŭ Terlik' (í)?

- Ekzistas decido de la Akademio de 2013 pri propraj nomoj, kie oni asertas ke ekzistas 3 manieroj trakti nomojn: plena esperantigo, parta esperantigo, kaj originala skribo. Okaze de parta esperantigo, la akcento restas nedifinita (bedaŭrinde)

  - Terlik estas parta esperantigo, ĉar oni (supozeble) prononcas ĉiujn literojn laŭ la sonoj en Esperanto sed ne ekzistas la finaĵo -o nek estas klare sur kiu silabo kuŝas la akcento.
  - Jen la ligilo por la Oficiala Informo de la Akademio: http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/oficialaj_informoj/oficialaj_informoj_22_2013.html
- Pli frue ol tiu oficiala informo, ekzistis rimarko en la Oka Oficiala Aldono al la Universala Vortaro kie oni asertis ke nomoj kiel Zamenhof kaj Vaŝington egalas al Zamenhof' kaj Vaŝington' (kun apostrofo, do kun klara akcentado)

  - Jen la ligilo: http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/aktoj/aktoj2/8oa.html
  - Tiu rimarko ne plu estas valida. Mi iom bedaŭras ke la nova decido estas malpli klara ol ĉi tiu, sed mi komprenas ke ne estis tute klare kiel apliki ĝin (ĉu por ĉiuj nomoj kiuj finiĝas per konsonanto?)
- Bertilo (PMEG) ankaŭ lasas la demandon kun malfermitaj ebloj: http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/ne-esperantaj_vortoj.html#i-vdi. Per aliaj vortoj, pluraj prononcoj eblas en tiaj okazoj.

Comment: Ĉi tion vi bone argumentis, kaj vi aldonis interesajn fontojn. Do nun ŝajnas al mi pli klare, ke por eltrovi la veran prononcon de _Terlik_ oni devus scii la originon de la nomo; tion oni ne povas trovi en la libro laŭ mia scio, ĉar temas pri unuiĝinta kaj artefarita mondoj; aperas ankaŭ (supozeble) itala nomo kaj iu nomo skribita per _x_, do ili verŝajne ne estas Esperantigitaj (ja almenaŭ transliteritaj).

Comment: Se aperas nomo kun “x”, ĝi apartenas al la kategorio “originala skribo” (aŭ transliterita de la originala skribo), kaj ĉiu ajn prononco estas (teorie) valida. Oni povas supozi ke oni prononcas tiun literon kiel “ks”, sed ĝi povus esti “z”, “gz”, “ŝ”, “ĥ” aŭ io ajn. Krome, la sonoj de la aliaj literoj ankaŭ fariĝas necertaj.

Comment: Jes, vi tute pravas. Do verŝajne ekzaktan respondon al mia demando oni ne povas havi (krom “demandu la verkiston”).

Answer (score 1):

Ŝajnas al mi ke la aŭtoro sekvas la jenan regulon pri akuzativigo de personaj nomoj: aldonu -n kiam fonetike eblas. Aldonu -on kiam ne.

Ĉu ni havas bonan kialon supozi ke fremda nomo kiel Terlik havas la akcenton sur la antaŭlasta silabo? Mi mem supozas ke ne, kaj mi prononcus la nomon jene:

- Terlík
- Terlík-on

Comment: Jes, tiun regulon ankaŭ mi suspektis. Interesas min specife via lasta komento; kial vi supozas, ke oni prononcus la nomon kiel _Terlík_? La sola kialo, kiun mi havas, por mia prononcmaniero estas simple, ke mi legis ĝin kiel normalan Esperantan vorton. La nomoj venas aŭ de futura, ŝajne kuniĝinta versio de nia mondo, aŭ de artefarita mezepokeca mondo, do ne vere eblas inferenci la ĝustan prononcon de la origino de la nomo.

Comment: "Normala" Esperanta nomo finigxus per -o. Tial mi legis gxin kie fremda vorto. Nur tial. Certe eblas vidi gxin alimaniere.

Comment: Tio havas sencon; do vi efektive legis ĝin kiel _Terlik'_. Estas aliaj nomoj, pri kiuj mi opinius tian prononcon eble iomete stranga (ekz. _Klaŭstropolis_); sed fakte ne vere estas sciebla la prononco, kiun la aŭtoro intencis. Sed se ni supozus, ke la prononco ja estus _Térlik_, ĉu vi ŝanĝus la akcenton en _Terlik-on_?

Comment: Nu, tio estas granda "se". Miaopinie: se la auxtoro intencas ke oni prononcu gxin "Térlik", li skribu "Térlik". Due, se la nomo vere estus Térlik, mi sekvus la regulon "aldonu -n se fonetike eblas" -- kaj sekve en akuzativo la nomo estus "Térlik" - kaj tute ne "Térlikn" aux "Térlik-on"